# ESLint dollar($) is not defined. (no-undef)

Tags: jquery, eslint

I added ESLint to my project. Everything is fine, except when it comes to the symbol `$`.

```
$("#ID").hide();
```

I get this error: `[eslint] '$' is not defined. (no-undef)`

My `.eslintrc.json` (note: it has [additional rules](https://github.com/dgraham/eslint-plugin-jquery) set to disallow jQuery functions when there's an equivalent JavaScript one):

```
{
"env": {
    "browser": true,
    "commonjs": true,
    "es6": true
},
"extends": [
    "eslint:recommended"
],
"parserOptions": {
    "sourceType": "module"
},
"plugins": [
    "dollar-sign",
    "jquery"
],
"rules": {       
    "indent": [
        "error" ,
        "tab"
    ],
    "linebreak-style": [
        "error",
        "windows"
    ],
    "quotes": [
        "error",
        "double"
    ],
    "semi": [
        "error",
        "always"
    ],
    "jquery/no-ajax": 2,
    "jquery/no-animate": 2,
    "jquery/no-attr": 2,
    "jquery/no-bind": 2,
    "jquery/no-class": 2,
    "jquery/no-clone": 2,
    "jquery/no-closest": 2,
    "jquery/no-css": 2,
    "jquery/no-data": 2,
    "jquery/no-deferred": 2,
    "jquery/no-delegate": 2,
    "jquery/no-each": 2,
    "jquery/no-fade": 2,
    "jquery/no-filter": 2,
    "jquery/no-find": 2,
    "jquery/no-global-eval": 2,
    "jquery/no-has": 2,
    "jquery/no-hide": 2,
    "jquery/no-html": 2,
    "jquery/no-in-array": 2,
    "jquery/no-is": 2,
    "jquery/no-map": 2,
    "jquery/no-merge": 2,
    "jquery/no-param": 2,
    "jquery/no-parent": 2,
    "jquery/no-parents": 2,
    "jquery/no-parse-html": 2,
    "jquery/no-prop": 2,
    "jquery/no-proxy": 2,
    "jquery/no-serialize": 2,
    "jquery/no-show": 2,
    "jquery/no-sizzle": 2,
    "jquery/no-slide": 2,
    "jquery/no-text": 2,
    "jquery/no-toggle": 2,
    "jquery/no-trigger": 2,
    "jquery/no-trim": 2,
    "jquery/no-val": 2,
    "jquery/no-wrap": 2,
    "dollar-sign/dollar-sign": [
        2,
        "ignoreProperties"
    ]
}
```

You can see that I have added two plugins: [eslint-plugin-dollar-sign](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-dollar-sign) and eslint-plugin-jquery.

Why doesn't this rule work?

```
"dollar-sign/dollar-sign": [
    2,
    "ignoreProperties"
]
```

Answer (score 281, accepted):

You are missing

```
"env": {
  "browser": true,
  "commonjs": true,
  "es6": true,
  "jquery": true
},
```

`$` is not declared as a global without `jquery` environment enabled. Because of that, you are getting a `no-undef` error, saying that you are using variable that haven't been declared.

Answer (score 57):

https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-environments

You can specify environments using a comment inside of your JavaScript file, use the following format:

Add the line below as a comment at the beginning of your JavaScript file.

```
    /* eslint-env jquery */
```

The eslinter will stop throwing undefined on '$' because it will know you are working with jQuery.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That saved me from changing configuration files.

Comment: Thanks! This is a lot clearer in intent than `/* global $ */`

Answer (score 34):

You can also add this line to the top of your js file:

```
/* global $ */
```

To prevent warning over "$", or for any other global like "varName":

```
/* global varName */
```

Comment: Worked perfectly adding "u" for umbrellajs : )  (figured i'd google the problem with "$" as it's probably more common)

Answer (score 28):

In `.eslintrc.js`

Add

```js
{
  "globals": {
    "$": true
  }
}
```

See https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-globals

Comment: this is good for other libraries, in my case THREEjs. I fixed the eslint complaining by adding `"globals": {
    "THREE": true
  },` thanks!

Comment: Been searching all day for this solution looking for webpack globals, this is just wbhat I needed. Thanky you!

Answer (score 1):

"env": {
....
"jquery": true
},

is really help.