# $ is not defined, but it still works perfectly

Tags: jquery

I am doing my first project with JQuery and it works fine. The weird thing is that I always get the Error:`'$' is not defined. [no-undef]` anyways.

Can I anyone tell me what the problem is?

This is how I put my JS at the end of the body:

```
<script src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/script.js"></script>
<script src="../js/Game.js"></script>
```

Comment: 1) Where do you see the error? 2) Which line of code is it referring to?

Comment: no-undef looks like a linter message rather than a browser error?  If so see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39510736/eslint-dollar-is-not-defined-no-undef

Comment: I only get it when I am working with Brackets or trying to validate it online.
And it's referring to every line I use '$' in

Comment: ESLint checks code for possible errors and violations of coding conventions. Since you have never declared a variable `$` in your code ESLint tells you that. It only works because your HTML loads jQuery in a  `script` tag (which ESLint cannot know).

Answer (score 0):

By the flag `[no-undef]` I guess that this is not Javascript error, but rather ESLint error, caused by the fact that you are referencing `$` which is defined in the other file.

In order to make ESLint happy you would have to declare `$` as global variable by placing `/* global $ */` at the top of your file.

Comment: this works, thanks
But i am still confused, because I don't even know what ESLint is (I am very new to all this)