# Getting to run jQuery - $ is not defined Error

Tags: javascript, html, eslint, adobe-brackets

Hello I'm new to Javascript, i'm trying to get to run jQuery library but Chrome notifies this error to me.
I did search a few posts about this in Stack Overflow and on Google but even so to me at least i couldn't find a satisfactory answer (i checked to have put jQuery script as first). Here is my HTML source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Responsive Design</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/slick.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/slick-theme.css">
        <!--<script type="text/javascript"  src="js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>-->
         <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
       <script src="js/slick.min.js"></script>


    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <a href="" class="logo">

                        <img src="" alt="">
                    </a>
                    <nav>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Work</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Clients</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Our Team</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header> 
           <section class="slider">
               <ul class="slider-carousel" id="#slider-carousel">
                   <li class="img1">
                       <h2>BEAUTIFIED BUSINESS <span>TEMPLATE</span></h2>
                       <p>We believe in creativity always</p>
                       <i class="fab fa-apple"></i>
                       <i class="fab fa-android"></i>
                       <i class="fab fa-windows"></i>
                       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio modi ducimus aut nihil explicabo, quia voluptatibus. Sint consequatur culpa vel sapiente, et dicta ratione facere distinctio, maiores modi eligendi. Perspiciatis.</p>
                       <a href="" class="btn btn-half">Get Started</a>
                       <a href="" class="btn btn-full">Buy Now</a>
                   </li>
                   <li>
                       <h2>Slider</h2>
                   </li>
                   <li>
                       <h2>Slider</h2>
                   </li>
               </ul>
           </section>   
           <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my directory structure:

```
**Project
 |
 +-- index.html
 |    
 +-- js
 |  |  
 |  -- bootstrap.min.js
 |  -- jquery-3.4.1.min.js
 |  -- main.js
 |  -- slick.min.js
 |    
 +-- css
 |  |  
 |  -- all.css
 |  -- bootstrap.min.css
 |  -- slick.css
 |  -- slick-theme.css
 |  -- style.css
 |    
 +-- images
 |  |  
    -- slider1.jpg
```

This is the single line of code i run:

```
$(Document).ready(function(){})
```

ERRORS I GET IN BRACKETS:

ESLint (2)

ERROR: 
'$' is not defined. [no-undef]  $(Document).ready(function(){})

ERROR: 'Document' is not defined. [no-undef]    $(Document).ready(function(){})
 JSLint (7)

'$' was used before it was defined. $(Document).ready(function(){})

'Document' was used before it was defined.  $(Document).ready(function(){})

Expected exactly one space between 'function' and '('.  $(Document).ready(function(){})

Expected exactly one space between ')' and '{'. $(Document).ready(function(){})

Missing space between ')' and '{'.  $(Document).ready(function(){})

Missing 'use strict' statement. $(Document).ready(function(){})

### Expected ';' and instead saw '(end)'.   $(Document).ready(function(){})

(I tried to load both, the local jQuery script and the other, but none of them seemed to work though)
{Thank you for your attention}

Comment: This seems like a linter error, rather than an actual problem with including the script. make sure your linter knows that you use jQuery, so it knows `$` is global.

Comment: should also be `document` not `Document`. JS variable names are case-sensitive.

Comment: @ADyson you are right, i typed document too, still have the same trouble

Comment: Where do you see these errors exactly? As vlaz says, they look mostly like linter errors. Have you tried actually running the script in your browser?

Comment: @ADyson i see the errors on Brackets console

Comment: ok ok! got it, i see the errors come only from Brackets, not from chrome console, the code runs nicely.

Comment: but still i dunno why is giving to me those errors.

Comment: In that case, read Vlaz's first and second comments again. You appear to be using ESLint, so the errors are coming from there (or most of them, anyway). Check its configuration.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39510736/eslint-dollar-is-not-defined-no-undef 1. Configure your linter 2. consider following the rules you have in your linter. That will remove the errors. If you don't want to lint your code, then just remove ESLint entirely.

Answer (score 2):

You must have a .eslintrc.json file.

Make sure you have the following lines of code in it:

```
   "env": {
     "browser": true,
     "commonjs": true,
     "es6": true,
     "jquery": true
   },
   "plugins": [
      "dollar-sign",
      "jquery"
   ],
   "rules": { 
      "dollar-sign/dollar-sign": [
          2,
          "ignoreProperties"
       ]
   }
```

You can read more here: https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#configuration-file-formats

Comment: just in case, i used jQuery instead of '$' symbol, the problem was still the same, i'll check it, thanks.

Comment: Done bens, still the same problem

Comment: @ArturoBolívarLabautdelRío try this ( based on this ) https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-environments   add at the beginning of your main.js file /*eslint-env jquery*/  and maybe /* global $ */  also can you add in your eslintrc.json file {
  "globals": {
    "$": true
  }
}